# Fat fingered YouTube, got some "fatal-crash" website

Tags: windows, google-chrome, virus

So I was typing in “youtube” (in Chrome using a Windows 7 machine) and fat fingered it to “gyoutube,” I ended up at some site with the address `http://fatal-crash.xyz` with a bunch of additional stuff.

I got a red screen with a Chrome-looking Google Security Alert, like the one you get when you go to a page that it can't authenticate (with the "Go to safety button).  A pop-up popped up (obviously) and said that my computer was infected with the “yahlover” virus and I needed to contact tech support with a phone number and a bunch of other stuff.

I didn't fall for that, but, like an idiot, I clicked the “x” in the upper right hand corner of the pop-up, which immediately returned.

After that, I tried to close Chrome, which didn't work, so I did the hard-reboot (hold the power button until it shut down).

I ran AVG and Microsoft Security Essentials and both come up clean (both are up to date).

I found some page where some lady said to run the Chrome Cleanup Tool and to delete the browsing and search histories.

I'm just trying to figure out if this is a scam or if there is a high probability that I ended up with the virus on my computer.

Comment: `After that, I tried to close Chrome, which didn't work, so I did the hard-reboot (hold the power button until it shut down).` - Why didn't you just kill the task?

Answer (score 1):

This is clearly a scam! I am not concerned that the virus warning of that site has some base. The only thing I'd be concerned is if I mistakenly agreed/downloaded something while on that site.

For a second opinion run the [Malwarebytes](https://www.malwarebytes.org/mwb-download/thankyou/) program. (and BTW running two real time anti-virus software - you said you have AVG and Microsoft Security Essentials - is very not good and could potentially make a lot of problems, uninstall one of them.)